# Eliminating unnecessary vacant spaces for a better presentation

Tags: math-mode

I am writing a LaTeX document and I am having this issue multiple times.

I was writting a proof, and after description on page 18, I began writing the equations inside

```
\begin{align}
\theta(x) &=\sum\limits_{ p \leq x } \operatorname{log}p \\
    .
    .
    .

\end{align}
```

But to my surprise instead of starting on page 18 itself, there is an unnecessary vacant space at the end of page 18 and the equations inside \begin{align} . . . \end{align} starts from a new page.
I am attaching an image for your reference.
[image: Code_Output]
Please note that because of some restrictions I am using TexStudio along with MiKTeX.

Comment: Probably your set of equations was too long to fit on the page, and you should add to your preamble `\allowdisplaybreaks`. Unrelated: for a display equation, need to add  `\limits`  to `\sum`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked! I will update \sum\limits too.

Comment: And `\log` is much simpler than `\operatorname{log}`.